# WALA Call Graph

Tags: java, static-analysis

I'm very new to WALA and trying to work through some simple examples to get a feel for it. I'm trying to build a call graph for the very simple class below

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        int z = x + y;
        Math.pow(x, y); // issue here
    }
}
```

My WALA code (simplified somewhat) is:

```
import com.ibm.wala.ipa.callgraph.*;
import com.ibm.wala.ipa.callgraph.impl.Util;
import com.ibm.wala.ipa.cha.ClassHierarchy;
import com.ibm.wala.util.WalaException;
import com.ibm.wala.util.config.AnalysisScopeReader;
...

AnalysisScope scope = AnalysisScopeReader.makeJavaBinaryAnalysisScope(jar, null);
ClassHierarchy cha = ClassHierarchy.make(scope);
Iterable<Entrypoint> entryPoints = Util.makeMainEntrypoints(scope, cha);
AnalysisOptions opts = new AnalysisOptions(scope, entryPoints);
AnalysisCache cache = new AnalysisCache();
CallGraphBuilder cgBuilder = Util.makeZeroCFABuilder(opts, cache, cha, scope);
CallGraph cg = cgBuilder.makeCallGraph(opts, null);
```

It works fine when the example doesn't have any calls to other methods inside main, but just hangs otherwise (stuck `cgBuilder.makeCallGraph`).

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have imports in your Example java file ?

Comment: I did not, but added `import java.lang.Math` and re-ran, but still seeing the hang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some options that might help making your run a bit faster

1) consider removing the reflectionOptions from your analysis options. This will not be great for more complex code, but for the basic example it might help
you can do so by

```
options.setReflectionOptions(ReflectionOptions.NONE);
```

2) try using a different builder
for example

```
ZeroXCFABuilder.make(cha, options, cache, null, null,
                ZeroXInstanceKeys.ALLOCATIONS | ZeroXInstanceKeys.CONSTANT_SPECIFIC);
```

There are more options, so check `ZeroXInstanceKeys`to see which options you might be willing to use.

3) finally, and this is probably going to give you a good run time, add exclusions

```
  String exclusionFile = p.getProperty("exclusions");
  AnalysisScope scope = AnalysisScopeReader.makeJavaBinaryAnalysisScope(appJar, exclusionFile != null ? new File(exclusionFile)
```

please note the following regex structure of an exclusion file

```
java\/awt\/.*
javax\/swing\/.*
sun\/awt\/.*
sun\/swing\/.*
com\/sun\/.*
sun\/.*
```

No spaces, single entry per line, etc.
this should help

Comment: I would assume that #3 it the most important one, good luck :)

Comment: @Quantico Have you any idea about javascript call graph generation?